# Join in @NamedQuery: Unexpected token ON

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join, named-query

In Hibernate, I created a query using `JOIN` to join two tables. The query executes fine in Oracles SQL Developer. However, if I add it to a `@NamedQuery`, the server starts with this error:

> Error in named query: loadFooByAnother: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near line 1, column xxx

My named query is:

```
SELECT foo FROM FooTable foo JOIN BarTable bar
  ON foo.something=bar.somethingId
    WHERE bar.anotherId=:another
```

Is it not possible to use `JOIN .. ON` syntax in Hibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `with` directive, if you use HQL:

```
SELECT foo 
FROM FooEntity foo 
JOIN foo.bar b with b.name = :name
WHERE foo.prop = :prop
```

This is for supplying a custom `ON` clause. From your example, judging from how you joined tables, I think you tried to execute a native SQL using a `@NamedQuery`.

If you want to run a native SQL query, you have to use [@NamedNativeQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQuery.html) instead.

If you want to use HQL, you need to use Entities and to join Entity associations (not tables).

If you use JPQL then the `with` directive has to be replaced by the `on` directive, but again, you need to navigate entity associations, meaning you have to map them first.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that there is ``@NamedQuery`` and ``@NamedNativeQuery``. I mixed up native SQL and HQL then. The only reference for the ``WITH`` keyword is in [this article](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins), though.